# How can I sort these comments so that the most recent appears at the top?

Tags: php, mysql

I currently have a MySQL database which contains any comment left on my webpage. I've then written the following script to make them appear on the page:

```
<?

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","theshitp_user","password");

if (!$con)
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("theshitp_posts", $con);


$query = "SELECT * FROM `userposts` LIMIT 0 , 30";

$comments = mysql_query($query);


while($row = mysql_fetch_array($comments, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{

  $comment = $row['comment'];
  $timestamp = $row['timestamp'];

  $comment = htmlspecialchars($row['comment'],ENT_QUOTES);

  echo "  <div style='text-align: center; border-style: solid; border-weight: 2px; border-radius: 5px; padding: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px; margin-left: 50px; margin-right: 50px;'>

      <h3>$comment</h3><br />
      $timestamp
    </div>
  ";
}

mysql_close($con);

?>
```

This posts the most recent comments at the bottom of the list. How can I modify this script to make it sort the comments in order of newest first?

Comment: Use order by on any date time field.

Comment: What would the code to do that look like? I'm very new to SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Use order by on any date time field, in your case i think its timestamp, like:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `userposts` ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 30";
```

This will show 30 records in descending order with respect to timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this query, you will get recent entries:

> $query = "SELECT * FROM `userposts` ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 0 ,
>   30";